# Downsampling and Gradient filtering

Tags: lowpass-filter, downsampling, gradient

Are the following sequence of operations the same -

- Down-sampling filtering followed by gradient filtering with kernel [-1 0 1]
- Gradient filtering with kernel [-1 0 1] followed by down-sampling

Could you point me to some math which can answer this question.

Intuitively, I am thinking that these operations are the same. That is because down-sampling can be loosely modeled as low-pass filtering and since convolution is associative, I guess they should produce similar results. But I am not able to quantitatively prove this to be a fact.

Comment: Definitely not the same - the gradient filter kernels are not equivalent as they are being applied at different sample rates. You would need to re-resample the gradient filter kernel in one of the two cases.

Comment: given that I have a 1080p image, would be easier to resample the signal or the filter?

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to achieve. You haven't explained the motivation for either the down-sampling or the gradient filter.

Answer (score 2):

As the commenters have stated, this is not the same. The relationships between down/up-sampling and filtering are formally described by the noble identities.

In your case down-sampling followed by filtering with [-1 0 1] is equivalent to filtering with [-1 0 0 0 1] first and than downsampling.

In any case you need to make sure your don't alias before down-sampling the picture.